# Сохранение файлов PDF

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Подскажите если у кого то был опыт сохранения файлов PDF в базе данных. Интересует вопрос стоит ли использовать данный способ хранения вообще или предпочесть файловые хранилища?

Comment: Был опыт. База растёт как на дрожжах - и тормозить начинает соответственно. В общем, дальше песочницы дело не пошло. Впрочем, опыт достаточно давний.

Comment: Спасибо Akina, я так понимаю не особо что то поменялось. Значит не стоит и пытаться.

Comment: Ну в общем для файлов придумана файловая система. Там файлы и храните... а в БД кладите - базовый каталог в служебную таблицу, относительный путь в рабочую.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю.